# validation for form is working,but popup box is not working HTML,Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, popup

i want a popup box with link to home page by clicking submit button only after validation.

How to create a popup box with a link to home page, triggered by a submit button only after validation in  HTML, and JavaScript?

validation is working in this form but popbox is not working.
i cnt find why this is not working?

```js
var subObject = {
  "place1": ["place1", "place2", "place3"],
  "place2": ["place4", "place4"],
}


window.onload = function() {

  var distSel = document.getElementById("district");
  var citySel = document.getElementById("city");

  for (var x in subObject) {
    distSel.options[distSel.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
  }
  distSel.onchange = function() {

    citySel.length = 1;


    var z = subObject[distSel.value];
    for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
      citySel.options[citySel.options.length] = new Option(z[i], z[i]);
    }
  }
}

function valid() {

  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
  var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];



  if (f1.username.value == "") {
    alert('enter the name');
    f1.username.focus();
    return false;
  } else if (f1.date.value == "") {
    alert('enter your date of birth');
    f1.date.focus();
    return false;
  } else if (f1.gender.value == "") {
    alert('Select gender');
    f1.gender.focus();
    return false;
  } else if (f1.district.value == "") {
    alert('select your district');
    f1.district.focus();
    return false;
  } else if (f1.city.value == "") {
    alert('select your city');
    f1.city.focus();
    return false;
  } else {



    btn.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }


    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    }

  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

form {
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=date] {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: #FF5733;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

select {
  height: 30px;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  padding-left: 290px;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!--model div open-->

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">

      <h2>Application Accepted</h2>
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Go Back To Home Page <a href="home">Home</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--model div close-->


Form code:

<form method="post" name="f1" action="">


  <h2 style="padding-left:50px">Application Form</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="uname">Name</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="uname" name="username" required>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="date">Date Of Birth</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="date" id="date" name="date" required> </td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>Gender</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>
                    <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" required> Female</label>
        <label>
                    <input value="male" type="radio" name="gender"> Male</label>
      </td>
    </tr>





    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="district">District</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="district" id="district">
          <option value="">---Select District---</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="city">City</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="city" id="city">
          <option value="">---Select District First---</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>




        <button type="submit" id="myBtn" class="cancelbtn" onclick="return valid()">SUBMIT</button>



      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding event handlers in your else part in valid function you just need to show the modal in the else.

```js
var subObject = {
  "place1": ["place1", "place2", "place3"],
  "place2": ["place4", "place4"],
}


window.onload = function() {

  var distSel = document.getElementById("district");
  var citySel = document.getElementById("city");

  for (var x in subObject) {
    distSel.options[distSel.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
  }
  distSel.onchange = function() {

    citySel.length = 1;


    var z = subObject[distSel.value];
    for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
      citySel.options[citySel.options.length] = new Option(z[i], z[i]);
    }
  }
}

var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function valid() {
  if (f1.username.value == "") {
    alert('enter the name');
    f1.username.focus();
    return false;
  } else if (f1.date.value == "") {
    alert('enter your date of birth');
    f1.date.focus();
    return false;
  } else if (f1.gender.value == "") {
    alert('Select gender');
    f1.gender.focus();
    return false;
  } else if (f1.district.value == "") {
    alert('select your district');
    f1.district.focus();
    return false;
  } else if (f1.city.value == "") {
    alert('select your city');
    f1.city.focus();
    return false;
  } else {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    return false; // added return false here because form will try to refresh and submit at this point.
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

form {
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=date] {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: #FF5733;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

select {
  height: 30px;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  padding-left: 290px;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!--model div open-->

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">

      <h2>Application Accepted</h2>
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Go Back To Home Page <a href="home">Home</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--model div close-->

<form method="post" name="f1" action="">


  <h2 style="padding-left:50px">Application Form</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="uname">Name</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="uname" name="username" required>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="date">Date Of Birth</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="date" id="date" name="date" required> </td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>Gender</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" required> Female</label>
        <label>
          <input value="male" type="radio" name="gender"> Male</label>
      </td>
    </tr>





    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="district">District</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="district" id="district">
          <option value="">---Select District---</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="city">City</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="city" id="city">
          <option value="">---Select District First---</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>




        <button type="submit" id="myBtn" class="cancelbtn" onclick="return valid();">SUBMIT</button>



      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: still its not working @CodeThing

Comment: @ayisha Seems working fine for me. Updated code with builtin editor. Run the snippet and check.

Comment: why my data that typed in form is still there after submit button .i added form action ,still there @CodeThing

Comment: @ayisha It doesn't clear automatically. You have to tell the code to clear it. You can add `f1.reset();` just before last `return false;` in the else part.

Comment: actually am using this code in python django, before this popup problem all the data enterd to database .but after this popup is working then data is not entering in to database .can you help me? @CodeThing

Comment: Try removing final return false; statement in the valid function. If it did not resolve, I would suggest you create new question with your updated code.